# How to prevent the reading of a text file from stopping at an empty line?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My problem is that my input file contains empty lines (this is a must), but when it reaches an empty line, the: `for i, line in enumerate(file):` stops reading the file. How do I prevent this.?

The reading of the file is like this, because I need to do something with every one but the last line of a file, than something else with the last line. (This is also a must.)

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
    i = 0
    for i, line in enumerate(file):
        # Do for all but last line
        if i < linecount-1:
            print "Not last line"
        i += 1
        # Do for last line
        if i == linecount-1:
            print "Last line"
```

It works fine on files without empty lines.

Comment: File iteration definitely doesn't care if a line is empty or not (consider that there is no such thing as an empty line really -- there's just two newlines in a row).

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to declare or increment `i` in your code. `enumerate` does that for you. Incrementing additionally as you do probably triggers your conditionals accidentally; it has nothing to do with empty lines.

Comment: Ok, but how else could I differentiate between the last line and the others without using `i`?

Comment: Enumerate gives you the proper value of i with each pass of the for loop. I am not saying get rid of i, I'm saying get rid of manually declaring and incrementing it, and just use enumerate. You can still test i against linecount.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to do the same without `i`
This doesn't work:
    `with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
        for line in enumerate(file):
            # Do for all but last line
            if line < linecount-1:
                print "Not last line"
            # Do for last line
            if line == linecount-1:
                print "Last line"`

Comment: Just remove the two lines `i = 0` and `i += 1` from your original code and keep the rest.

Answer (score -1):

The mistake in your implementation is explained in the other answer, but to achieve what I think you want to do, it might be better to process as follows, then you don't need to know the length of the file in advance:

```
import sys

def process_regular_line(line):
    print 'regular line', line

def process_last_line(line):
    print 'last line:', line

with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
    last_line = file.readline()
    while True:
        this_line = file.readline()
        if not this_line:
            process_last_line(last_line)
            break
        process_regular_line(last_line)
        last_line = this_line
```

For example, on the test file with 5 lines:

```
a line
another line

a line after a blank line
The last ever line
```

You get:

```
regular line: a line

regular line: another line

regular line: 

regular line: a line after a blank line

last line: The last ever line
```